# Getting the error of subprocess to the master when using rdd.pipe

Tags: apache-spark, rdd

When using `rdd.pipe(command)`, the error of subprocess does not come back to the master. For instance, if one does:

```
sc.parallelize(Range(0, 10)).pipe("ls fileThatDontExist").collect
```

The stacktrace is then the following:

```
java.lang.Exception: Subprocess exited with status 1
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PipedRDD$$anon$1.hasNext(PipedRDD.scala:161)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PipedRDD$$anon$1.foreach(PipedRDD.scala:153)
    at scala.collection.generic.Growable$class.$plus$plus$eq(Growable.scala:48)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:103)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.$plus$plus$eq(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.to(TraversableOnce.scala:273)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PipedRDD$$anon$1.to(PipedRDD.scala:153)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toBuffer(TraversableOnce.scala:265)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PipedRDD$$anon$1.toBuffer(PipedRDD.scala:153)
    at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.toArray(TraversableOnce.scala:252)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.PipedRDD$$anon$1.toArray(PipedRDD.scala:153)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1$$anonfun$12.apply(RDD.scala:885)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$collect$1$$anonfun$12.apply(RDD.scala:885)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1767)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1767)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:63)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:213)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Driver stacktrace:
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1273)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1264)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1263)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1263)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:730)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:730)
    at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:236)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:730)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1457)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1418)
    at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
```

No mention here of the error that happened in the command, one needs to search in the executor logs to find:

```
ls: fileThatDontExist: No such file or directory
```

Checking the code of PipedRDD, it appears that one could add more information when throwing the exception (like adding the content of proc.getErrorStream in the message):

```
val exitStatus = proc.waitFor()
if (exitStatus != 0) {
  throw new Exception("Subprocess exited with status " + exitStatus)
}
```

I have two questions regarding this. Is there a reason for not doing so? Also does anyone know a shortaround?

For now I have encapsulated process execution so that when there is an error in the process, I return 0 and output the stderr of the process plus a marker. The RDD is then mapped and lines containing the marker throws an exception with the stderr.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of now (Spark 1.6), the current behavior is to [print the stderr](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-1.6/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/rdd/PipedRDD.scala#L122) of the process spawned in the standard error output of the executor. This seems to be a very early choice from Spark's very own creator, Matei Zaharia, as you can see [here](https://github.com/apache/spark/commit/23b1c309fbbba70999177be319525c197c9fa72b), dating back from 2011. I don't see any other way to collect the stderr in the current implementation.

Recently a change has been pushed to Spark 2.0 to propagate any exception from the child process to the calling process (see [SPARK-13793](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-13793)), and a minor change has been added to the exception thrown when the exit status is different than 0 (see this [line](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/rdd/PipedRDD.scala#L177)).

This could be proposed as an improvement, let me know if you need any help to suggest this as an enhancement to Spark.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, should I just file a JIRA for this with a possible fix?

Comment: @geoalgo Yes you can create a JIRA as an Improvement, however you might want to wait before making any pull request until an experienced Spark developer comes around on your issue to see if this is a wanted behavior or not. You can then suggest a fix once we know for sure. I'll look around for your issue on JIRA !